Как поменять местами столбцы в CSV?
как csv поменять местами столбцы?
abc,321,&!?
hjk,654,?*%
zbj,456,)&#
fhj,785,$`=

результат, второй и третий столбец поменяли местами
abc,&!?,321
hjk,?*%,654
zbj,)&#,456
fhj,$`=,785

как это сделать с помощью утилит cmd awk, или любой способ

Excel, Google Spreadsheets?

Какая ОС для утилит?

@rotabor ubuntu

Вот так, например:
csvcut -c column_c,column_a data.csv > new.csv
или
csvtool col 1-3,6 input.csv > output.csv

abc,321,&!?
hjk,654,?*%
zbj,456,)&#
fhj,785,$`=  


awk -F, '{print $1","$3","$2; }' test.txt


abc,&!?,321
hjk,?*%,654
zbj,)&#,456
fhj,$`=,785

